# How to set driver-memory and driver.memoryOverhead in spark-submit client mode

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

I'm using CDH version CDH 5.13.3, spark-2.3.0. Refering to the document https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/configuration.html, I set driver memory and driver memoryOverhead, but it doesn't work

```
spark2-submit \
--class my.Main \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--driver-java-options "-Ddriver-memory=5g" \
--conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=3g \
--num-executors 33 \
--executor-cores 4 \
--executor-memory 8g \
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=4g \
```

I expect that spark job gets 8g (driver-memory 5g + memoryOverhead 3g) in the beginning, but on yarn ui it only has 2g

Answer (score 0):

You need pass the driver memory same as that of executor memory, so in your case :

```
spark2-submit \
--class my.Main \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--driver-memory=5g \
--conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=3g \
--num-executors 33 \
--executor-cores 4 \
--executor-memory 8g \
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=4g \
```

Also, The values you pass here doesnt guarantee and depends upon the actual cluster configuration. Also asking for more memory means your job will wait untill you get executors available with the specified configurtions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it, but it did not work.Refering to the document https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/configuration.html, Note: In client mode, this config must not be set through the SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has already started at that point. Instead, please set this through the --driver-memory command line option or in your default properties file.